# Why my webpack build worked so strange after adding resolve options of webpack configuration?

Tags: webpack-4, webpack.config.js

Actually,I don't know how to explain my question.At beginning,I come across some problem when I add resolve.alias to my webpack output modules———it doesn't work after my adding!then I found there're two resolve options in the output modules,then I merged them,but throw an error.And my webpack is the newest.

I just want to use the path alias when import modules.

that's the worked code(but the @ alias doesn't work):

```
...
modules.export={
...,
resolve: {
        alias: {
            'react-dom': '@hot-loader/react-dom',
            '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/app/'),
        },
    },
resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.css']
    },
}
```

that's the code that caused errors:

```
...
modules.export={
...,
resolve: {
        alias: {
            'react-dom': '@hot-loader/react-dom',
            '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/app/'),
        },
       extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.css']
    },
}
```

I wanna know whether that's the right form or there are other reason why the code worked like this.

Answer (score 0):

I thought that I just found solution to this problem. If some friends met this problem.You could try it according to my solution.Just a moment before, I thought may be caused by the react-hot-loader module.And the configuration I showed was the way to use react-hot-dom,I tried another way that use:

```
yarn add react-dom@npm:@hot-loader/react-dom
```

Then,I removed the alias configuration for react-dom.It worked now.[The code worked without throwing errors now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vg5Fe.png)